Quotient of Laurent polynomial $\Bbb Z_2 [x,x^{-1}]$ by submodule generated by $1+x$
Hi I'm having trouble to find a neat identification of the quotient $$L:=\dfrac{\Bbb Z_2 [x,x^{-1}]}{\langle 1+x\rangle}$$
I'm tempted to say that as (abelian) groups, $$L \cong \dfrac{\Bbb Z_2 [x,x^{-1}]}{\langle x\rangle}\cong \Bbb Z_2$$
but as $\Bbb Z_2 [x,x^{-1}]$-modules the latter has clearly the trivial action while $L$ comes equipped with an action that is less "trivial", I.e. $x$ acts as the identity.
Am I missing something or did something wrong? Thanks!

Is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ the field on $2$ elements or the $2$-adic integers?

field on 2 elements! sorry about the confusion in notation

Hint: $L \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y] / \langle xy-1, x+1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y] / \langle x+1, y+1 \rangle$.

@DanielSchepler I see. using your second identification then I think I can see that as groups $L$ and $\Bbb Z_2$ are the same, as I am killing the two variables by forcing the equal to $1$. The action though is different.

Right, as a $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,x^{-1}]$-module it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with $x$ and $x^{-1}$ both acting as the identity.  (Or if you were using $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the 2-adic integers, then it would be $x$ and $x^{-1}$ both acting as negation...)

It is indeed $$\dfrac{\Bbb Z_2 [x,x^{-1}]}{\langle x+1\rangle}\cong \Bbb F_2.$$
That $x+1$ is identified with $0$ implies [in  $\mathbb{F}_2$] that $x$ is identified with $1$. Indeed, $x+1=0 \implies (x+1)+1 = 0+1 \implies x=1$.
